# How to add items programatically to the Telerik MVC TabStrip?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik

Does anyone know how to programatically add tabs in the Telerik tabstrip?

Comment: Is this link any help: http://www.telerik.com/community/code-library/aspnet-ajax/tabstrip/initialize-update-radtabs-programmatically-code-snippet.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take use of databinding and add items to the underlying datasource, as this will automatically be displayed in the TabStrip. For more information refer to [this documentation article](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-tabstrip-data-binding.html).